# AWSMediaConvert client throwing error for VideoDescription width using Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, openjdk-11, aws-media-convert

I am using AWS Java API for creating AWS Elemental MediaConvert job with VideoDescription width 1920. When I invoke createJob() method using AWSMediaConvert client, it throws error saying ->

```
com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.model.BadRequestException: /outputGroups/0/outputs/2/videoDescription/width: Should be less than or equal to 832 (Service: AWSMediaConvert; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: e794fca3-2e80-4953-8b05-1a303f5ec1c9; Proxy: null)
```

Searched in google as well as was elemental mediaconvert docs, I did not find any solution. Apart from VideoDescription width, other job setting details are proper.

Using below dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.823</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.823</version>
        </dependency>
```

Could anyone tell why I am getting this error?

Is there any dependency of resolution width on another job setting parameter?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MediaConvert has some pre-validation rules before it will create a job. Settings such as output resolution, bitrate, and frame rate need to fall in compliance with whatever video codec specification you are attempting to create. This is dictated by Profile and Level you are using for a given codec.

The service has an AUTO option for the Profile Level setting. This will allow the encoder to choose the best Level with the given settings, if there is one. If the encoder cannot determine a valid level, the job will ERROR and provide the following error code and message:

1040
No valid level could be found. Check profile.

Here are a list of some supported MediaConvert video codecs and their profile and level limitations:

H.264 Profile/Level
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels

H.265 Profile/Level
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding_tiers_and_levels

MPEG2 Profile/Level
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.262/MPEG-2_Part_2#Video_profiles_and_levels